# Retrieve all sitecollections and its subsites using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

How to retrieve all the Site Collections along with its subsites from SharePoint online using PowerShell. Please suggest.

Comment: try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604076/use-powershell-to-retrieve-all-subsites-for-sharepoint-online

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete script to get all sites in a site collection from SharePoint Online:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\folder\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "c:\folder\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"



$siteUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection"

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com", $password)

$ctx.Credentials = $credentials



$rootWeb = $ctx.Web

$sites = $rootWeb.Webs



$ctx.Load($rootWeb)

$ctx.Load($sites)

$ctx.ExecuteQuery()



foreach($site in $sites)

{

  $ctx.Load($site)

  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()



  Write-Host $site.Title "-" $site.Url

}
```

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/24/create-and-manage-sharepoint-online-sites-by-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. Is there a way to get all the sitecollections initially and then loop through it to get its subsites? As am new to powershell, i do not have much idea